# How to write text format when proto including google::protobuf::Any

Tags: protocol-buffers

My proto is something like:

```
message PlatformConfig {
  google.protobuf.Any source_adapter_config = 1;
};
```

and I want to set proto:

```
message SessionBundleSourceAdapterConfig {
  SessionBundleConfig config = 1;
}
```

into `source_adapter_config`, How to write the this TextFormat of protobuf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found that Any type need a type_url to specify type, for example:

```
platform_configs {
    key: "tensorflow"
    value {
        source_adapter_config {
            type_url:"type.googleapis.com/tensorflow.serving.SavedModelBundleSourceAdapterConfig"
            value: "..."
        }
    }
}
```